# iOS : How to upload an image from a URL to Parse?

Tags: ios, file-upload, parse-platform

I'm able to upload an image (in form of `PFFile`) on parse with their methods available.

```
NSData *data = ... ;
PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithData:data];
[file saveInBackground];
```

Is there a better way to directly upload an image from a url to parse?

**Update:** The bad way I found is,

To get an image from `NSURL` to `NSData` - don't know about the proper way, but this is working. Something like this,

```
PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlObj]];
[file saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is how best to get the data to pass to parse.  You're right that `dataWithContentsOfUrl` is a bad way because it blocks the main thread during the fetch.

Here's a block-based approach to get the data asynchronously:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:// ..."];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithData:data];
        [file saveInBackground];
    }
}];
```